# How can I automatically calculate a payment on page load using javascript?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I want to calculate loan payment automatically, after loading a page. For the payment calculation I have javascript function `calculatePayment(field.form)`.

I have four variables, which can be changed by users. By default I am going to use information from the current post (E.g. price of the car, 5.5% interest, 5 years, 10% downpayment from the car price):

```
<p><label class="loan-title" for="l-amount"><?php _e('PRICE:  '.$symbols['currency'].'','language')?></label> 
                <input type="text" size="10" name="price" value="<?php if ( $fields['price']){ echo $fields['price'];} else {  echo '0'; };?>"  class="l-inputbar" id="l-amount" onBlur="checkForZero(this)" onChange="checkForZero(this)"></p>
            <p><label class="loan-title" for="l-down"><?php _e('DOWNPAYMENT:  '.$symbols['currency'].'','language')?></label>
                <input type="text" size="10" name="dp" id="l-down"   class="l-inputbar" value="<?php if ( $fields['price']){ echo $fields['price']*0.1;} else {  echo '0'; };?>"  onChange="calculatePayment(this.form)"></p>
            <p><label class="loan-title" for="l-amount"><?php _e('PROCENTU LIKME: %','language')?></label>
                <input type="text" size="5"  name="ir" value="5.5" class="l-inputbar" onBlur="checkForZero(this)" onChange="checkForZero(this)">    </p>                    
            <p><label class="loan-title" for="l-amount"><?php _e('PERIOD: (years)   ','language')?></label>
                <input type="text" size="4"  name="term" value="5" class="l-inputbar"  onBlur="checkForZero(this)" onChange="checkForZero(this)">  </p>         
            <p class="calculate-wrapper"><input type="button" name="cmdCalc" value="" class="calculate-btn" onClick="cmdCalc_Click(this.form)" onLoad="calculatePayment(this.form)" ></p>
            <p><label class="loan-title" for="l-amount"><?php _e('MONTHLY PAYMENT: '.$symbols['currency'].'','language')?></label>
                <input type="label" size="12"  class="l-inputbar"  name="pmt"></p>
```

All the data loads into input fields, but I can't find the solution how to calculate the payment on page load. I have tried all the javascript function calls. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: window.onload=function() { .... }

Comment: When is the user changing these fields? That has to happen before you try to calculate. Page load happens before anything, so I don't understand why you are trying to use page load. You can either call the calculatePayment(field.form) function when you update a value or click a "Calculate" button when you are done changing values.

Comment: I have tried different options and this is just a last one. Can you give me exact description how to call this function after I have updated and how to click "Calculate" button (automatically) when I have done changing values?

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery's *document.ready()* or *$(function(){ / * your stuff here * / })* which does the check, whether the document is loaded and rendered. It's a bit more complex than *window.onload*, so I would recommend you to use a framework (anyway).

Comment: I tried all options which are mentioned in previous answers and comments, but still no results. I am not developer, thus I might be doing something wrong. Could you please provide me with more detail answer giving exact example?